# Can a Muslim use a college degree that He / She earned by cheating in some of their Exams?

Tags: halal-haram, work

Assalamu Alaikum to my Brothers in Islam,

**SCENARIO**: A Muslim cheats in the college exams by any means (Copying, Peeking etc) and without cheating he or she couldnt have passed the exam.

Because of cheating he/she passed the exams. and so this made them eligible to earn the degree (B.Sc, B.A, MBBS, B.Com etc)

1) Is such a degree Halal or Haram? Can a person use this degree to get interviews and secure jobs?

2) If he or she does secure a job, will the earning be considered halal or will it be devoid of Barakah?

3) What is the best course of action for a Muslim who has obtained a degree by cheating and is still unemployed and is searching for a job?

Comment: The earning will be halal if you did your job well. The diploma or degree  might be a juridical Issue. Cheating per se is not halal.

Comment: So lets say the person hasn't gotten a job yet and is searching for one, can he use this degree that he obtained by cheating in exams to apply and secure a job?